# As a greencard holder, is it okay to have international trip every 3 month, each approximately 1 week?

Tags: usa, immigration, citizenship

I have a significant other leaving abroad and I want to visit them every 3 or 4 months. Currently, I am a permanent resident. Is it okay if I travel abroad every 3 or 4 months and stay outside of the US for about 1 week each time?

Comment: You already asked this question on the Expatriates SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you've got a green card, which means you're good to travel outside of the U.S. The tricky part is, if you're out of the country too much, Immigration might start thinking you're not really living in the U.S anymore, which could mess with your permanent resident status.

But here's the good news: if you're planning to jet off every 3 or 4 months, but only for about a week each time, you're probably fine. That's not long enough to look like you're trying to move your whole life somewhere else.

Just remember, it's not just about how often you're traveling. They'll also look at stuff like whether you're working in the U.S, if you've got family here, if you own property, and other ties you've got to the country.

And another heads up, if you're thinking about becoming a U.S citizen someday, you've got to be in the U.S for at least half of the five years before you apply (or three years if you're married to a U.S citizen).